hyperref warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string - macro Refactoring as a fix
I have a macro that takes a comma-separated list of lists and applies some formatting to it. The list consists of the first and last names of the document's authors. I managed to create a macro - \stringifiedAuthorsList (certainly not the best implementation - see the code below) which mainly capitalizes the last name of any author in the list (\authors) and makes the first name title case. Until this point, everything goes well.
The problem arises when I try to use this macro in conjunction with the hyperref package's \hypersetup macro to set a value for the pdfauthor option, or when I set the package option pdfusetitle and try to fill the built-in macro \author with the output of my macro. The compiler gives me this warning:
Package hyperref: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref) removing `\stringifiedAuthorsList'

When I searched for how to fix this, I found various suggestions, with the three most common being:

Fix 1: Disable the problematic command via \pdfstringdefDisableCommands; This way, the warning disappears, but this is not a solution since I need the author metadata field to be filled with the authors' names and not ignored.

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
    \def\stringifiedAuthorsList#1{#1}
}


Fix 2: Use \texorpdfstring{TEX string}{PDF string}; This method is not feasible as I don't want to manually set the PDF string part.
Fix 3: Redefine the macro to be expandable; Mainly using \NewExpandableDocumentCommand instead of \NewDocumentCommand.

I found that the third fix is the one I should use, but the problem persists because the \formatAuthorList function is not expandable as well, so it needs to be redefined in an expandable way too. At this point, I have run out of solutions because the unexpandable code itself took me a lot of trial and error to make it work.
Could you lend a helping hand in refactoring/rebuilding that macro? I am sure there is a better and cleaner solution I am missing.
Feel free to suggest any method you find efficient to handle this problem.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \clist_new:N \g_my_authors_clist

    \NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}{
        \clist_gset:Nn \g_my_authors_clist { #1 }
    }
    
    \NewDocumentCommand{\stringifiedAuthorsList}{}{
        \formatAuthorList:n { \g_my_authors_clist }
    }

    \cs_new_protected:Npn \formatAuthorList:n #1{
        \clist_new:N \l_my_tmpp_clist
        \clist_map_inline:Nn #1{
            \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}{
                \seq_clear_new:N \l_my_tempa_seq
                \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_my_tempa_seq { , } { ##1 }
                \tl_if_blank:eTF {\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tempa_seq { 1 }}{
                    \tl_if_blank:eF {\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tempa_seq { 2 }}{
                        \clist_put_right:Ne \l_my_tmpp_clist {\MakeUppercase{{\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tempa_seq { 2 }}}}
                    }
                }{
                    \tl_if_blank:nF {\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tempa_seq { 2 }}{
                        \clist_put_right:Ne \l_my_tmpp_clist {\MakeUppercase{\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tempa_seq { 2 }}~\MakeTitlecase{\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tempa_seq { 1 }}}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        \clist_use:Nn \l_my_tmpp_clist { ,~ }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\authors{%
    {firstName1, lastName1},
    {firstName2, },
    {, lastName3}
}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor = \stringifiedAuthorsList % Sets the document information Author field
}

% \author{\authorsListStringified}

\begin{document}

\stringifiedAuthorsList
% Desired output: LASTNAME1 Firstname1, Firstname2, LASTNAME3

\end{document}


There is a fourth option: Modify your formatting macro so that it stores the formatted names in a macro \pdfauthorlist (or some other name) instead of leaving it in the input stream. This is then expandable and can be used anywhere. Your formatting macro only has to be called once and does not need to be expandable.

@schtandard Thanks for the reply. Do you have any idea how exactly I can do that?

you should follow the naming scheme and always use a module name. \l_tmpp_clist should be \l_mycroft_tmpp_clist, \g_authors_clist should be \g_mycroft_authors_clist etc. And do no use \clist_new:N \l_tmpp_clist inside your command, at the next call it will error.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for the feedback. If I understand correctly, the naming scheme you’re suggesting means that any defined variable should follow the format \⟨scope⟩_⟨module⟩_⟨name⟩. Is this convention mainly to produce cleaner code and prevent naming conflicts, or is it something required by the LaTeX compiler to function correctly?

If you like expl3's e-expansion, then s.th. like the following might do the trick—due to usage of \clist_map_tokens:nn and \clist_use:nn this requires expl3 2021-05-10 or later:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\clist_new:N \g_my_authors_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_my_authors_clist { #1 }
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Nn \__mystuff_deblankclist:n {
  \exp_not:e { \tl_if_blank:nTF{#1}{{}}{\__mystuff_deblankclistloop:n{#1}} }
}
\cs_new:Npn \__mystuff_gobbletocomma:w #1,{}
\cs_new:Nn \__mystuff_deblankclistloop:n {
  {  
    \int_compare:nNnT {\clist_count:n {#1}}={\clist_count:n {{}#1}}
                      {\clist_item:nn {#1}{1}}
  }
  \tl_if_empty:oF{\__mystuff_gobbletocomma:w #1,}{
     ,\exp_args:No \__mystuff_deblankclistloop:n {\__mystuff_gobbletocomma:w  #1 }
  }
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
% \processAuthorList <clist-variable>
%                    {<formatting-command for last names>}
%                    {<tokens between entire names>}
%                    {<formatting-command for first names>}
%                    {<tokens before first names>}
% The result is wrapped in \exp_not:n = \unexpanded .
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Nn \processAuthorList:Nnnnn {
  % #1 list 
  % #2 formatting-command for last names
  % #3 tokens between entire names
  % #4 formatting-command for first names
  % #5 tokens before first names
  \exp_args:Ne \exp_not:e {
  \exp_args:Ne
  \clist_use:nn 
  {
    \clist_map_tokens:Nn #1{ \mystuff_process_name:nn {{#5}{#4}{#2}}  }
  }{\exp_not:n{#3}}
  }
}
\cs_new:Nn \mystuff_process_name:nn {
  \exp_not:n {
     \exp_args:Nne
     \use:n { \mystuff_process_name:nnnn #1 }{\__mystuff_deblankclist:n {#2}}
  },
}
\cs_new:Nn \mystuff_process_name:nnnn {
  % #1 tokens before first names
  % #2 formatting-command for first names
  % #3 formatting-command for last names
  % #4 list with name
  \tl_if_blank:eF {\clist_item:nn {#4}{-1}} {
    \exp_not:n{#3}{\clist_item:nn {#4}{-1}}
  }
  \int_compare:nNnTF {\clist_count:n {#4}} > {1} {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF {\clist_item:nn {#4}{-1}} {
      \mystuff_process_nameloop:nnnnn {1}{}
    }{
      \mystuff_process_nameloop:nnnnn {1}{#1}
    }{#2}{#4}{#1}
  }{}
}
\cs_new:Nn \mystuff_process_nameloop:nnnnn {
  % #1 item number
  % #2 tokens before first names in 1st iteration
  % #3 formatting-command for first names
  % #4 name list
  % #5 tokens before first names
  \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {\clist_count:n {#4}}
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eF {\clist_item:nn {#4}{#1}} {
      \exp_not:n{#2#3}{\clist_item:nn {#4}{#1}}
    }
    \exp_args:No \mystuff_process_nameloop:nnnnn{\int_eval:w #1+1\scan_stop:}{#5}{#3}{#4}{#5}
  }{}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Npn \stringifiedAuthorsList {
  \use:e{%
    \processAuthorList:Nnnnn  
      \g_my_authors_clist
      {\text_uppercase:n}
      {,~}
      {\text_titlecase:n}
      {~}
  }%
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \AuthorsListTable {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:nn {
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    \hline
  }{
    Author\int_compare:nNnT {1} < {\clist_count:N \g_my_authors_clist}{s}:&
    \processAuthorList:Nnnnn
      \g_my_authors_clist
      {\text_uppercase:n }
      {\\&}
      {\text_titlecase:n}
      {~}
  }
  \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOff

\authors{%
    {firstName1, lastName1},
    {firstName2, },
    {, lastName3},
    {firstName1A, firstName1B, firstName1C, lastName1},
}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor = {\stringifiedAuthorsList} % Sets the document information Author field
}


\begin{document}

\stringifiedAuthorsList

\bigskip

\AuthorsListTable

\end{document}



Thank you so much! Not only did you answer my question, but your comments also helped me discover new things. (I'll accept this answer since it was the first to propose a solution to my question).

Process one author at a time adding items in a sequence. Then use this sequence in the way you need.
In order that Unicode characters are honored, the input has to be presented before \hypersetup acts.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}
  {
    \mycroft_authors_input:n { #1 }
    \AtBeginDocument{\exp_args:Ne \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\seq_use:Nn \g_mycroft_authors_seq {;~}}}
  }
% \printauthors will be part of \maketitle
\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{}
  {
    %\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    %\seq_use:Nn \g_mycroft_authors_seq { \\ }
    %\end{tabular}
    \seq_use:Nn \g_mycroft_authors_seq { ,~ }
  }

\seq_new:N \g_mycroft_authors_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mycroft_authors_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mycroft_authors_input:n
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_mycroft_authors_seq
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
       \__mycroft_authors_process:n { ##1 }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mycroft_authors_process:n
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mycroft_authors_temp_seq { , } { #1 }
    \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_mycroft_authors_seq
      {
        \tl_if_blank:eF { \seq_item:Nn \l__mycroft_authors_temp_seq { 2 } }
          {
            \text_uppercase:n { \seq_item:Nn \l__mycroft_authors_temp_seq { 2 } }
            \tl_if_blank:eF { \seq_item:Nn \l__mycroft_authors_temp_seq { 1 } } { ~ }
          }
        \seq_item:Nn \l__mycroft_authors_temp_seq { 1 }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\authors{
  {Firstnáme1, Lastname1},
  {Firštname2, },
  {, Lastnamě3},
}

\begin{document}

\printauthors
% Desired output: LASTNAME1 Firstname1, Firstname2, LASTNAME3

\end{document}



As always, your answers are both simple and efficient. Thanks for your reply! @egreg

When I use some accented characters, they get replaced by strange letters in the metadata. How can I fix this? @egreg

@Mycroft_47 Fixed in the new version
